# How to add a virtual/mock camera device internally/externally to android 11+ and set it as the default camera?

Tags: camera, android-11

I need a virtual camera to override the system camera on android 11+ phone to stream frames that are sourced from an image file. Basically injecting image into the camera device.

I need it to test camera functionality on mobile native apps/webapps.
I would have easily done it with a custom camera app before Android 11 but now it isn't possible. See [link](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/behavior-changes-11#media-capture)!

Assume that I have both root access and unlocked bootloader on my phone.

Any Ideas?

---

Ideas that I was thinking of:

1. Emulating a external USB camera to feed only an image: But how do I set it as a system camera?
2. Adding a loopback device as a kernel module and makng it the default camera device. https://github.com/umlaeute/v4l2loopback